# Reach element without tag with CSS

Tags: css

I work with a developers team with they do a paging but the Current paging is not into any HTML tag which they create dynamically is that any way with Css to call this element with knowledge that i cant edit style for it inline because its dynamically not just HTML code

```
    <tr class="paging">
<td colspan="3">
1 
<a href="/ManageAccounts/ManageRestaurantsBars?page=2">2</a> 
<a href="/ManageAccounts/ManageRestaurantsBars?page=3">3</a> 
<a href="/ManageAccounts/ManageRestaurantsBars?page=4">4</a> 
<a href="/ManageAccounts/ManageRestaurantsBars?page=2">&gt;</a> 
<a href="/ManageAccounts/ManageRestaurantsBars?page=4">&gt;&gt;</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

i wanna call the 1 elemnt

Comment: depends on what kind of style you want to give it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on what kind of styling you want to apply..

for properties that do not affect the [`box-model`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html) of the element you can do it..

for example

```
.paging td{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-style:italic;
    /*etcetera*/
}
```

and override those for the normal links with

```
.paging td a{
    color:white;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-style:normal;
    /*etcetera*/
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i want to give the one only a background color

Comment: @user1393257, can you post an image of the end result with the 1 and the other links in the image ? (it might be possible by manipulating the styling of the `td` to match that of the elements

Answer (score 0):

Just use the this

`tr.paging > td { font-weight:bold; }`

and if you don't want the `<a>` links bold then add...

`tr.paging > td > a { font-weight:normal; }`

-

Edit: A bit of fiddling with the margins but this approach will work: http://jsfiddle.net/trapper/sX94B/

Comment: This will style all pages `bold`

Comment: i am trying to give the 1 background color when i do for all the tr and overwrite it for the links was look so ugly

Comment: @trapper I know that, but I was just stating you should point out this won't *just* style the `1`

Comment: `background-color` is going to be tricky case because this will also effect the spaces between and around the `<a>` tags. You may need a javascript solution for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution similar to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617593/885443) that will give a background color to only `1` by fiddling with the margin and padding of the anchor elements:

```
tr.paging td {
  background: red; 
}

tr.paging a {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0 -2px;
}
```

Not very elegant, but it works.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKcPg/1/)